# insert, update, delete using Cardview , RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have done this with listview.
Now I am new in cardview.
I'm getting this error:

```
E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.dell.databaseusingcardview;

public class StudentTable {
    public int _id;
    public String _name;
    ...
    public String _subject2;
    public String _subject3;

    public StudentTable() {
    }

    public StudentTable(int id, String name, String phone_number, String email, String subject1, String subject2, String subject3) {
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        .....
        this._subject3 = subject3;
    }

    public StudentTable(String name, String phone_number, String email, String subject1, String subject2, String subject3) {
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
        ...
        this._subject3 = subject3;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this._name;
    }

    .....

    public void setSubject3(String subject3) {
        this._subject1 = subject3;
    }

    public String getSubject3() {
        return this._subject3;
    }
}
```

**SqliteHelper class:**

```
package com.example.dell.databaseusingcardview;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
....
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "STUDENT_DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "STUDENT_RECORD";
    public static final String C_ID = "id";
    public static final String C_NAME = "name";
    private static final String C_PH_NO = "phone_number";
    private static final String C_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String C_SUBJECT_1 = "subject1";
    public static final String C_SUBJECT_2 = "subject2";
    public static final String C_SUBJECT_3 = "subject3";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + C_NAME + " TEXT, " + C_PH_NO + " TEXT, "+ C_EMAIL +" TEXT, " + C_SUBJECT_1 + " TEXT, " + C_SUBJECT_2 + " TEXT, " + C_SUBJECT_3 + " TEXT )";
    private final ArrayList<StudentTable> student_list = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    public void insert_student(StudentTable studentTable) {
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(C_NAME, studentTable.getName());
        ...
        contentValues.put(C_SUBJECT_3, studentTable.getSubject3());

        myDataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        myDataBase.close();
    }

    StudentTable Get_Student(int id) {
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{C_ID, C_NAME, C_PH_NO, C_EMAIL, C_SUBJECT_1, C_SUBJECT_2, C_SUBJECT_3}, C_ID + " =? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        StudentTable studentTable = new StudentTable(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3), c.getString(4),c.getString(5),c.getString(6));
        c.close();
        myDataBase.close();
        return studentTable;
    }

    public void update(StudentTable studentTable) {
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(C_NAME, studentTable.getName());
        ...
        contentValues.put(C_SUBJECT_3, studentTable.getSubject3());

        myDataBase.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, C_ID + " =? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(studentTable.getId())});
        myDataBase.close();
    }

    public void delete(int id) {
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        myDataBase.delete(TABLE_NAME, C_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        myDataBase.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<StudentTable> Get_Student(){
        try {
            student_list.clear();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

            myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    StudentTable student = new StudentTable();
                    student.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    student.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                   ....
                    student.setSubject3(cursor.getString(6));
                    student_list.add(student);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            myDataBase.close();
            return student_list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("all_student", "" + e);
        }

        return student_list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**Insert_Update_View Classs**

```
package com.example.dell.databaseusingcardview;

import android.app.Activity;
.....
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Insert_Update_View extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText add_name, add_mobile, add_email, add_subject1, add_subject2, add_subject3;
    Button add_save_btn, add_view_all, update_btn, update_view_all;
    LinearLayout add_view, update_view;
    String valid_mob_number = null, valid_email = null, valid_name = null,
            Toast_msg = null;
    int STUDENT_ID;
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_sub);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Set_Insert_Screen();

        String called_from = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");

        if (called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {

            add_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            update_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            update_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            add_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            STUDENT_ID = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("STUDENT_ID"));

            StudentTable s = sqliteHelper.Get_Student(STUDENT_ID);

            add_name.setText(s.getName());
            ...
            add_subject3.setText(s.getSubject3());
        }

        add_mobile.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) { }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Is_Valid_Sign_Number_Validation(12, 12, add_mobile);
            }
        });
        add_mobile
                .addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());

        add_email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Is_Valid_Email(add_email);
            }
        });

        add_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Is_Valid_Person_Name(add_name);
            }
        });

        add_save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (valid_name != null && valid_mob_number != null
                        && valid_email != null && valid_name.length() != 0
                        && valid_mob_number.length() != 0
                        && valid_email.length() != 0) {

                    sqliteHelper.insert_student(new StudentTable(valid_name,
                            valid_mob_number, valid_email, add_subject1.getText().toString(),
                            add_subject2.getText().toString(), add_subject3.getText().toString()));
                                    Toast_msg = "Data inserted successfully";
                                    Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
                                    Intent view_user = new Intent(Insert_Update_View.this,
                                            MainActivity.class);
                                    view_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(view_user);
                                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast_msg = "error";
                }
            }
        });

        add_view_all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent view_user = new Intent(Insert_Update_View.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                view_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(view_user);
                finish();
            }
        });

        update_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                valid_name = add_name.getText().toString();
                valid_mob_number = add_mobile.getText().toString();
                valid_email = add_email.getText().toString();

                // check the value state is null or not
                if (valid_name != null && valid_mob_number != null
                        && valid_email != null && valid_name.length() != 0
                        && valid_mob_number.length() != 0
                        && valid_email.length() != 0) {

                    sqliteHelper.update(new StudentTable(STUDENT_ID, valid_name,
                            valid_mob_number, valid_email, add_subject1.getText().toString(), add_subject2.getText().toString(),
                            add_subject3.getText().toString()));
                    sqliteHelper.close();
                    Toast_msg = "Data Update successfully";
                    Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
                    Intent view_user = new Intent(Insert_Update_View.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    view_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(view_user);
                    finish();*/
                } else {
                    Toast_msg = "Sorry Some Fields are missing.\nPlease Fill up all.";
                    Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
                }

            }
        });
        update_view_all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent view_user = new Intent(Insert_Update_View.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                view_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(view_user);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void Set_Insert_Screen() {

        add_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
       ....
        add_save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert_btn);
        update_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_btn);
        update_view_all = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_view_btn);

        add_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_buttons_linearlayout);
        update_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.update_buttons_linearlayout);

        add_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        update_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void Is_Valid_Sign_Number_Validation(int MinLen, int MaxLen,
                                                EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException {
        if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            edt.setError("Number Only");
            valid_mob_number = null;
        } ....
        else {
            valid_mob_number = edt.getText().toString();

        }

    }

    public void Is_Valid_Email(EditText edt) {
        if (edt.getText().toString() == null) {
            edt.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            valid_email = null;
        } else if ...
        } else {
            valid_email = edt.getText().toString();
        }
    }

    boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    public void Is_Valid_Person_Name(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException {
        if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
            valid_name = null;
        } else if ...
        } else {
            valid_name = edt.getText().toString();
        }

    }

    public void Show_Toast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void Reset_Text() {

        add_name.getText().clear();
        ...
        add_subject3.getText().clear();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.insert) {
            Intent add_student = new Intent(Insert_Update_View.this,
                    Insert_Update_View.class);
            add_student.putExtra("called", "add");
            add_student.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(add_student);
            finish();
        }
        if (id == R.id.update) {
            Intent add_user = new Intent(Insert_Update_View.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            add_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(add_user);
            finish();
        }
...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**MainActivity :**

```
package com.example.dell.databaseusingcardview;
import android.app.Activity;
....
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView studentlist;
    ArrayList<StudentTable> studentTables = new ArrayList<>();
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper;
    RecyclerView rv;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        try {
            rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            Set_Referash_Data();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("some error", "" + e);
        }
    }

    public void Set_Referash_Data() {
        studentTables.clear();
        sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
        ArrayList<StudentTable> student_array_from_db = sqliteHelper.Get_Student();

        for (int i = 0; i < student_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

            int tidno = student_array_from_db.get(i).getId();
            String name = student_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
            ...student_array_from_db.get(i).getSubject3();
            StudentTable stud = new StudentTable();
            stud.setId(tidno);
            stud.setName(name);
           ....
            stud.setSubject3(subject3);

            studentTables.add(stud);
        }

        sqliteHelper.close();
        mAdapter= new RecyclerView_Adapter();
        rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Set_Referash_Data();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.insert) {
            Intent add_student = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Insert_Update_View.class);
            add_student.putExtra("called", "add");
            add_student.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(add_student);
            finish();
        }
       ...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    }

     class RecyclerView_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView_Adapter.studentHolder>{
        List<StudentTable> studentlist;
        StudentTable stud;

        public RecyclerView_Adapter() {
            studentlist = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        @Override
        public studentHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup v, int i){
            View item = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, v, false);
            return new studentHolder(item);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(studentHolder holder, int position) {
            stud = studentlist.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(stud.getName());
            holder.email.setText(stud.getEmail());
            holder.number.setText(stud.getPhoneNumber());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return studentlist.size();
        }


    public class studentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView email;
        protected TextView number;
        protected Button edit;
        protected Button delete;

        public studentHolder(View v){
            super(v);

            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.student_name_txt);
            email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.student_email_txt);
            number = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.student_mob_txt);
            edit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
            delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity is having problem i guess, but i dont know much in cardview so, please help out.